# readable argparse arguments without -- or -

Tags: python, argparse

So i think argparse is very good but how i can do somthing like this in argparse/python?

For example:

```
myprog del <username>    (remove only config entry)
myprog del -A <username> (remove all of the user...)
myprog add <username> (must be 1 sub-arg, not more)
myprog change <old-username> <to-new-username>   (must be 2 sub-args, not more)
myprog list (no sub argument)  
myprog list -A (list ALL)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything with the [sub commands](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands)?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a straight forward case for using subparsers

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands

Adapting the example from the documentation

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
...
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmd', help='sub-command help')

# create the parser for the "a" command
parser_a = subparsers.add_parser('del', help='a help')
parser_a.add_argument('username', ...)
parser_a.add_argument('-A', type='store_true')

# create the parser for the "b" command
parser_b = subparsers.add_parser('add', help='b help')
parser_b.add_argument('username')

# change gets 2 positionals
# list gets one -A
....
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.cmd == 'del':
    # delete args.username
....
```

`args.cmd` tells you which command was given.   The documentation (and other SO questions) shows how you can associate a function with each command.